# Why was I wrong doing this problem?

Tags: probability, statistics

"A waste disposal company averages $6.5$ spills of toxic waste per month. Assume spills occur randomly at a uniform rate, and independently of each other, with a negligible chance of $2$ or more occurring at the same time. Find the probability there are $4$ or more spills in a $2$ month period."

The way I did it was to first say "the probability of a spill on a random selected day is $\frac{65}{300}$ (assuming $30$-day months)". Then I calculated the probability that there will be $3$ or $2$ or $1$ or no spills over $600$ days, then I subtracted it from 1. I got a tiny answer (a few percent), but the correct solution was $0.9989$. What did I do wrong, and why is the correct answer $0.9989$?

Comment: Why $\mathbf{600}$ days?  Besides, if there are $6.5$ spills on average in one month, and so $13$ on average in two months, most people would guess that it is _very_ likely that $4$ or more spills occurred in the two month period, not a few percent.

Comment: Yes, but I still don't know why I'm wrong. Changing it to 60 days would only make the probability tinier.

Comment: Maybe if you typed in the formula you used to calculate the probability of $3$ or fewer spills in $60$ days, it would help people to point out what you did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This sends up all sorts of red flags:

> I calculated the probability that there will be 3 or 2 or 1 or no spills over 600 days, then I subtracted 1 from it.

Since probabilities can't be greater than one, if you subtracted one from "the probability that there will be 3 or 2 or 1 or no spills" then you should have gotten a negative number.

Intuitively, you should have realized that if there are an average of 6.5 spills per month, the probability that there will be at least 4 over 2 months should be pretty high, so your low answer should have set off some mental alarms.

Have you learned about the [Poisson distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution)? That's the easy way to solve this problem.

Comment: I actually subtracted it from 1, not the other way around lol

Comment: @EricDong That's better, then. Still, the way the problem is written screams "Poisson distribution!"